# errors when resizing image in EBImage

Tags: r, image, resize

I tried to resize the image with the package EBImage. I want to resize the image with w=100 and h=200. but when im running the process I receive the following error:

> ERROR: in resize unused arguments (w = 100, h = 200)

The program stops running.

Why am I receiving this error?

```
im <- readImage('sample.png')  
y <- resize(im, w = 100, h = 200)
im <- channel(y, "grey")
write.csv(t(im), "sample.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a name clash with a function from another R package, and instead of `EBImage::resize` a function with a different set of arguments from the other package is called. To circumvent this try replacing your calls to `resize` by `EBImage::resize`. For further troubleshooting please provide a reproducible example illustrating the issue.